# Windows 7 hard disk failure - Re-enable warning

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I've previously disabled a hard disk failure warning in Windows before later removing the disk.

I've since done some further diagnostics and I now believe the SATA cable to be at fault, I've replaced the cable and reattached the hard disk and I'm now not getting the warning. But now I'm not sure if it's actually fixed the issue or if the warnings are still disabled on the disk. Is there any way to check if the warnings are still disabled for that disk or to re-enable them for all?

I've run SMART tests and they seem ok but they seemed ok whilst Windows was warning too.

Answer (score 0):

Most HD vendors have an adavanced test tool that goes beyond SMART.  Seagate has [SeaTools for Windows](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/) and Western Digital has [Data Lifeguard](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=612&sid=3).  You can run advanced tests with those tools.  Other manufacturers offer tools as well.  You can sometimes use one vendors tool to do tests on anothers drive but not always.